# Make a TextBox required if a certain Radio button is selected

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, radio-button

I want to attain that a textbox will be changed to required="true" if a certain radio value is selected as Cash

this is my html form:

```
<label class="radio"> <input type="radio" name="payment" value="Cash" id="cashpayment" checked><span><img width="30" src="images/icons8-cash-in-hand-48.png"/></span></label>
<label class="radio"> <input type="radio" name="payment" value="SD" id="sdpayment"><span><img width="30" src="images/icons8-budget-48.png"/></span></label>
<label class="radio"> <input type="radio" name="payment" value="Budget" id="budgetpayment"><span><img width="30" src="images/icons8-office-48.png"/></span></label>
```

here is my jQuery code (jQuery v3.3.1)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("input[name='type']:radio").change(function(){
        if($(this).val() == 'Cash')
        {
          $('#cashtender').attr('required');
        }
        else if($(this).val() == 'SD')
        {
          $('#cashtender').removeAttr('required');
        }
        else if($(this).val() == 'Budget')
        {
          $('#cashtender').removeAttr('required');
        }
    });
});
```

it's not working. please help

Comment: this is the code that i want to make a required if radio button "Cash" is selected
```
<input type="text" class="form-control form-control-lg" autocomplete="off" 
 id="cashtender" name="cashtender" />```

Answer (score 1):

I can see a couple  of mistakes:

1. Selector for the radio buttons is incorrect: `$("input[name='type']:radio")` should be `$("input[name='payment']:radio")`
2. When you set an attribute, you should provide value in the second argument or use prop: `$('#cashtender').attr('required');` should be `$('#cashtender').attr('required', 'required');` or `$('#cashtender').prop('required', true);`

Complete code (removed unnecessary `else if` condition):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("input[name='payment']:radio").change(function(){
        if($(this).val() == 'Cash')
        {
          $('#cashtender').prop('required', true);
        }
        else
        {
          $('#cashtender').removeAttr('required');
        }        
    });
});
```

Comment: hi. its not working. but if i have to select first the other option and re-select Cash it's the only time that prompt for Required. the Cash is the default selection.

Comment: @vinzenzsekunde if cash will always be the default selection, just make the `cashtender` text box required by default.